# How to achieve the Fiji "HiLo" colormap in matplotlib image plots, to mark under and overexposed pixels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, imagej, colormap, fiji

Matplotlib's colormaps do not provide the HiLo colormap for images, which is often used in microscopy. HiLo shows a gray-level gradient from low to high values, but values at the low-end are shown in blue and ones at the upper end in red.

How can one get this color-map for matplotlib images?

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this one can use the 'set_under' and 'set_over' methods of the LinearSegmentedColormap class, of which the colormaps are inherited.

```
# minimal example
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange

im_array = arange(0, 256)

cmap = cm.gray
cmap.set_over(color='red')
cmap.set_under(color='blue')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

vmin = im_array.min() + 1
vmax = im_array.max() - 1

ax.imshow(im_array.reshape((16, 16)), cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

[image: HiLo example]

May be this helps someone.
Cheers!
S